ath11k-pci: qcn9074: Use Regulatory Domain data from regulatory.db instead of wifi adapter's EEPROM
I'm using OpenWrt 23.05.05 (i compiled it for my custom system) and have two WiFi chips (QCN9074) that use the ath11k_pci driver. I also have a regulatory.db file located in /lib/firmware. I want to use this file as the source of regulatory data for the cards instead of their built-in regulatory data. Currently, they are self-managed as shown by "iw reg get," and I want to change this. Is it possible to do so?

Regulator agencies a while ago got involved in the making sure the manufactures were responsible for configuring this data. Based on what I know about that effort I don't believe you will find a way to change the data once it's been set by the manufacture. The last time I work with OpenWrt was back in 2014 and the regulatory changes had already happened.
